# Javascript conditional statements cause other functions to stop working

Tags: javascript, syntax

### Edit

I originally phrased this question as if browser detection was causing my problem, but it was simply caused by incorrect syntax.

1. Make sure to close all brackets (they should always come in pairs!)
2. Give your code some space (it will be easier to spot mistakes!)
3. Clean up your `if`-statements by moving messy conditional expressions into variables
4. Use semantic (ideally unambiguous) variable names — this makes it easier to understand what your code is trying to do

For example, the following:

```js
const layoutStyles = document.querySelector('#layoutStyles');
const testElement = document.createElement('div');

let supportsFlex = testElement.style.flex !== undefined;
let supportsFlexFlow = testElement.style.flexFlow !== undefined;

if (supportsFlex && supportsFlexFlow) {

  layoutStyles.setAttribute('href', 'flex-layout.css');

} else {

  layoutStyles.setAttribute('href', 'float-layout.css');
}
```

is technically equivalent to this:

```js
const cond = document.querySelector('#cond');
const tstEl = document.createElement('div');
if (tstEl.style.flex!==undefined&&tstEl.style.flexFlow!==undefined)cond.setAttribute('href','flex-layout.css');
else cond.setAttribute('href','float-layout.css');
```

but the latter is much harder to read and understand. Thus it is also harder to debug and refactor, and *easier to accidentally introduce errors*.

As the contributors wrote in their answers long ago, it's important to learn language basics; crawl before you walk, walk before you run!

---

For some reason, this portion of javascript is blocking out all the other functions I have written previously. They work if I take it out, and stop working when I put it back in.

If someone can spot what's wrong, please let me know! I'm not very good with JS really, so I'm not quite 100% sure what I'm even doing here.

Well, I used this as my reference; http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml

Here's my code:

```
//4th batch shows a warning box upon finding a visitor with an outdated browser
if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ //test for Firefox/x.x or Firefox x.x (ignoring remaining digits);
 var ffversion=new Number(RegExp.$1) // capture x.x portion and store as a number
if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ //test for MSIE x.x;
 var ieversion=new Number(RegExp.$1) // capture x.x portion and store as a number
if (/Opera[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ //test for Opera/x.x or Opera x.x (ignoring remaining decimal places);
 var oprversion=new Number(RegExp.$1) // capture x.x portion and store as a number
 
if (ffversion<11 || ieversion<9 || oprversion<11.6)
 function browserwarning()
 {
 document.getElementById('oldbrowser').style.display="inherit";
 }
 //END OF 4TH BATCH
```

Comment: In advance: Sorry if I'm being stupid. I know it's folly to mess around with a language you don't really know. ^^'

Comment: `RegExp.$1` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#RegExp_Properties) and should not be used. Also, function declarations inside if-blocks are invalid (Check http://kangax.github.com/nfe/, especially the section about "function statements") and will probably cause a syntax error. Check your error console.

Comment: That code is a mass of syntax errors, outdated techniques, and deprecated functionality. Wherever you got it from, I would recommend not using that reference again. All due respect, I strongly recommend hiring someone to do this work for you (or, of course, stepping right back and learning JavaScript, from the beginning). Somewhat separately: Browser detection is almost never a good idea. *Feature* detection, where you detect what the browser can and can't do, is usually a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot some closing brackets and function inside if-statesment are invalid. This code will work without syntax errors:

```
//4th batch shows a warning box upon finding a visitor with an outdated browser
if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) { //test for Firefox/x.x or Firefox x.x (ignoring remaining digits);
    var ffversion = new Number(RegExp.$1); // capture x.x portion and store as a number
} else if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)) { //test for MSIE x.x;
    var ieversion = new Number(RegExp.$1); // capture x.x portion and store as a number
} else if (/Opera[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) { //test for Opera/x.x or Opera x.x (ignoring remaining decimal places);
    var oprversion = new Number(RegExp.$1); // capture x.x portion and store as a number
}

if (ffversion < 11 || ieversion < 9 || oprversion < 11.6) {
    document.getElementById('oldbrowser').style.display = "inherit";
}
```

**But I highly recommend you to to some efforts in learning how to use and write javascript code. It looks like you are trying to write a letter in chinese although you don't even know their symbols...**

Comment: You don't put `;` after the closing `}` of a block.

Comment: @ Simon: For the same reason you write `if` in lower case: That's how the language is defined. Blocks are not expressions. You don't put semicolons after them. They end up being empty expressions, which are harmless, but they serve exactly no purpose and make the code odd to read.

Comment: I updated my anywer. But why does this not generate a syntay error then? I use semicolons to mark that a block has surely been finished, e.g. when binding multiple event handlers and chaining them.

Comment: @ Simon: I suggest reviewing the syntax of the language. Blocks never need semicolons after them, they're already "closed." You typically put semicolons after *expressions*. It's important to understand the difference and apply the rules correctly.

Comment: @ Simon: I hadn't noticed that in addition to putting in semicolons where you *don't* want them, you'd left out semicolons where you *do* want them. I've added those in for you.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I am actually trying to learn JavaScript, as I am currently web designer/developer for a festival of which I am also a member of the committee. Problem is, I have a bit of a difficulty making it stick, and also I am busy studying something completely different - dressmaking!

But yeah, thanks for your help, both of you :)
I will continue studying the basics, and hopefully I can get to the more complex part in a while.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of `{` with no corresponding `}`.

```
if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) { 
    var ffversion = new Number(RegExp.$1);
}
else if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    var ieversion = new Number(RegExp.$1);
}
else if (/Opera[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) { 
    var oprversion=new Number(RegExp.$1);
}

if (ffversion < 11 || ieversion < 9 || oprversion < 11.6) {
       document.getElementById('oldbrowser').style.display="inherit";
}
```

I just closed all brackets.

Anyway, I recommend that you take a loot at this: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html